# Jquery, select first next element after all anchors with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select first next element after all anchors with same class.
**HTML**

```
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_1">
</ul>
...
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_2">
</ul>
...
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_3">
</ul>
...
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_4">
</ul>
...
```

Now i want to select all `ul1,ul2,ul3,ul4`.
Here i tried :

```
console.log($(".some_anchors").nextAll('ul:first'));
```

But it returns `ul1` only.
How fix this issue?

Comment: you want to select the all ul?

Comment: There are many ul in my HTML. I want to select first next `ul` after all `anchors` with `some_anchors` class.

Comment: Loop through the result of `$(".some_anchors")` and [`add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) the `next('ul')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the next sibling selector `+` to target the ul directly after the class elements.

```js
console.log(
  $('.some_anchors + ul').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_1">
</ul>
<ul class="not-me">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_2">
</ul>
<ul class="not-me">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_3">
</ul>
<ul class="not-me">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_4">
</ul>
<ul class="not-me">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var lists = [];
  $(".some_anchors").each(function(i, el) {
    lists.push($(el).next());
  });
  console.log(lists);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_1">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_2">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_3">
</ul>

<a class="some_anchors">
</a>
<ul id="ul_4">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's may helpful to you

```js
  $('li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("some_anchors")) {
            $(this).show();

        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul>
    <li>li (No Class)</li>
    <li>li (No Class)</li>
    <li>li (No Class)</li>
    <li class="some_anchors">li (sibling with class name "some_anchors")</li>
    <li>li (No Class)</li>
    <li>li (No Class)</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```